# Is it possible to add type annotations to a method outside of my code?

Tags: python, type-hinting

Let's suppose I'm writing a Python plugin for a large, legacy codebase not under my control. That codebase exposes an object with several functions that I can call from my plugin code:

```py
def plugin_entrypoint(ctx: LegacyCodebaseObject):
   ...
```

One of these functions cause the plugin controller to terminate the plugin with an error condition:

```py
def plugin_entrypoint(ctx: LegacyCodebaseObject):
   ...
   ctx.fail(reason="foo", ...)  # never returns
```

However, being a legacy codebase, none of these functions are type-annotated. My plugin *is* type-annotated and I use mypy, which causes an annoyance because mypy thinks that `ctx.fail()` may return:

```py
def plugin_entrypoint(ctx: LegacyCodebaseObject):
   ...
   try:
      some_data = some_function()
   except Exception as e:
      ctx.fail(reason=f"Failed to prepare data: {e}")  # never returns

   other_function(some_data)  # mypy complains that some_data might be referenced before assignment
```

---

Is it possible to somehow annotate `LegacyCodebaseObject.fail()` from within my code in a way that mypy will understand?

I could simply wrap `ctx.fail()` into my own function annotated with Never type, but this would be unidiomatic and my plugin would not pass code review.

Comment: If it's legacy, consider releasing a [stub-only package](https://peps.python.org/pep-0561/#stub-only-packages) or [partial stub-only package](https://peps.python.org/pep-0561/#partial-stub-packages) if you need more typed API. This should be minimal effort - it's not like the legacy codebase will change anyway, so you don't even have to keep anything in sync.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to make use of `TYPE_CHECKING` and inheritance.

Let's assume the legacy code looks like this:

```py
# Deep inside the legacy codebase
class LegacyCodebaseObject:

  def foo(self):
    ...

  def bar(self, baz, *, qux):
    ...

  def fail(self):
    raise Exception
```

In the `TYPE_CHECKING` branch, import that to your code with an alias, then create a subclass with the correct name:

```py
if TYPE_CHECKING:
  from legacy_codebase import LegacyCodebaseObject as _LegacyCodebaseObject

  class LegacyCodebaseObject(_LegacyCodebaseObject):

    # Correct type hints here
    def fail(self, reason: str, **kwargs: Any) -> Never:
      ...

    # You can do the same for other methods as well
    ...
```

On the other branch, just import it as normal:

```py
else:
  from legacy_codebase import LegacyCodebaseObject
```