# How can I augment class type definition in Python?

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a 3rd party class with the following code

```py
class CBlockHeader(ImmutableSerializable):
    """A block header"""
    __slots__ = ['nVersion', 'hashPrevBlock', 'hashMerkleRoot', 'nTime', 'nBits', 'nNonce']

    def __init__(self, nVersion=2, hashPrevBlock=b'\x00'*32, hashMerkleRoot=b'\x00'*32, nTime=0, nBits=0, nNonce=0):
```

I want to tell the type checker that `nVersion` is of type `int` and I was able to achieve that by creating a `pyi` file and putting the following content in it

```py
class CBlockHeader:
    nVersion: int
```

Problem now is, the type checker is only looking at the class definition in my `pyi` file. So it doesn't see the other attributes or the `__init__` function or anything. To fix that, I would have to redefine all of these things in my `pyi` file when all I wanted was the type of the `nVersion` attribute.

If I can merge the original type definition with my `pyi` file that would fix the problem.

Is that possible? Or how is this situation handled in Python?

Edit: TypeScript has an ability similar to what I'm describing https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html Given the comments I'm seeing on my question, I'm guessing that Python simply doesn't have this.

Comment: If the type of the `nVersion` attribute is all you wanted, why is what you have shown not sufficient?

Comment: Not what you're asking, but do you really want your version to be int? What integer operations are you planning for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is it possible to add type annotations to a function outside of my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78059194/is-it-possible-to-add-type-annotations-to-a-function-outside-of-my-code). There must be a better target somewhere, but I can't find one yet.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Only `nVersion` has the incorrect type. The type checker is able to infer the other types from the original source code correctly.

Comment: @InSync That's not the same. The answer there is suggesting a very hacky workaround.

Comment: @M.K.Safi Maybe, but in that case, what kind of solution do you want?

Comment: @InSync What I'm looking for is possible in TypeScript (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html). But not possible in Python. Maybe the answer to this question is simply "No, the Python type system doesn't support this feature"