# Cannot access member "getOrCreate" for type "classproperty"

Tags: pyspark, pyright

I am using Pyspark inside VSCode using Pylance.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

I have this setting enabled:

```
"python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "basic",
```

With this, I get this error:

> Cannot access member "getOrCreate" for type "classproperty"
> Member "getOrCreate" is unknown Pylance (reportAttributeAccessIssue)

I haven't found any solution for this.

I read this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/4577

But according to them, they blame pyspark, but I haven't found anyone in pyspark that is aware of this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to add type annotations to a function outside of my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78059194/is-it-possible-to-add-type-annotations-to-a-function-outside-of-my-code)

Comment: "*I haven't found anyone in pyspark that is aware of this*": To make things worse, `@classmethod` can no longer wraps `@property` [since 3.11](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod). Pylance should [warn you about that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74FTT.png).

Comment: @InSync so there's nothing that can be done?

Comment: What I mean is that Pyspark's maintainers ought to deal with this problem that they created themselves. While `@classmethod` `@property` doesn't work at runtime, it's fine to let them be in the `TYPE_CHECKING` branch and ignore the deprecation warning.

Comment: ok, so I guess they have to deal with that and there's nothing that can be done from a code perspective.